# I am making momos at home and want to store them too

Tags: meat, dumplings

I am making chicken momos at home for the first time.My question was that if I want to fry the momos do I directly put them in the fryer or steam them first and then fry it.What will be the difference in taste and texture?I also want to store them for later use but I am finding that they stick together and become limp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! Momos are dumplings filled with meat and/or vegetables with savory spices. They are very similar to various Chinese dumplings or Japanese gyoza, but have a different flavor profile because of the type of spices used.

Dumplings of any kind can be served steamed or fried. All of the recipes I've ever seen for any type of dumplings call for them to be steamed before frying. While I can't say what the difference would be if they were fried without being steamed, I think the major difference would be the texture of the cooked dough.

When using a metal steamer insert it is recommended to lightly oil the bottom of the insert to prevent the dumplings from sticking. If using a bamboo insert, you would want to line the bottom with a folded tea towel.

After steaming, you do want to cool the dumplings before frying. I use a lightly oiled cooling rack. The slight amount of oil will keep the dumplings from sticking to the rack. Additionally, you don't want the dumplings touching each other. They *will* stick together if touching, and you run the risk of creating holes in them when pulling them apart.

For short term storage for fried dumplings, after the steamed dumplings have cooled on the rack, I place the rack(s) in covered plastic containers and place in the fridge until I am ready to fry them later the same day.

For short term storage for steamed dumplings, I place the uncooked dumplings on lightly oiled racks in plastic containers and place in the fridge until steaming later in the day. Remember that they shouldn't be touching.

Long term storage: You can make large batches of uncooked dumplings to cook at later times. You would want to place them on lightly oiled trays (not touching)  and place in the freezer. Once they are frozen, remove them from the trays and place in ziploc freezer bags and return to the freezer. When you want to cook them, do not thaw out - use from frozen. This will add a little to the steaming time but you do not want to thaw them first.

Next time I make dumplings I will take a couple and fry without steaming first. I will update with the results. I am a bit skeptical because traditional wisdom says to steam first, but who knows?

Side note: To add extra flavor to the dumplings, steam them over broth. We make a Chinese cabbage soup that has a similar flavor profile to a hot and sour soup. Steaming dumplings or meatballs over the soup adds another layer of flavor!

Answer (score 2):

The [first recipe I found online](https://food.ndtv.com/recipe-fried-chicken-momos-219246) says steam, then cool, then fry. What they don't say - and I think they should - is that they should be cooled without touching each other (and in fact touching as little as possible). I'd cool them on a rack but you might be able to use paper towel (it might stick).

If you're storing them for a little while after that and want to pack them together, a dusting of flour after they're cool should help. They should be dry to the touch by this point but the dough will still be a little sticky. Alternatively you could possibly brush them with oil before storage.